# TailwindCSS - Add many properties after media queries

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am learning ***tailwind*** these last days and I was wondering if there was any ways to "**group**" many properties after a media queries or a "hover:" for example.

```
 <a
    className="text-[#7E0000] no-underline text-xl mt-0 mb-3 pt-3 pb-3 relative z-0 cursor-pointer 
    after:left-0 after:bottom-0 after:absolute after:opacity-0 after:w-0 after:h-1 after:content-[''] after:bg-[#7E0000] after:transition-all after:duration-500"
    onClick={() => scrollToView("nous")}
  >
```

For example here, I have many properties that I want to add to "after:", is it possible to do a thing like : `after:{opactiy-0 bottom-0 left-0}` instead of `after:opacity-0 after:bottom-0`...

Thank you for your help

Comment: can you share a completed snippet. Its quite unfinished.